# Why is localhost:3000 rendering css differently than my app hosted on Heroku?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, github

When checking out my GUI in localhost:3000 running locally (rails server) everything looks right, but when I push the code up to Github and then to Heroku, the CSS appears to be rendering differently. Specifically, the problem I'm having is with this bit of css:

```
#searchfield {
    float: left;
    left: 10%;
    top: 1em;
    position:relative;
}
```

and the code in the view:

```
<div id="searchfield">
    <form method="get" action="http://www.amongu.com/search.rb"> 
        <input type="text" name="search" size="40px" placeholder="Search"> 
    </form>
</div>
```

For whatever reason, the css in the page online seems to be getting partially ignored, and thus the search-box is overlapping other elements. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks

EDIT: Here's my layout helper:

```
# These helper methods can be called in your template to set variables to be used in the layout
# This module should be included in all views globally,
# to do so you may need to add this line to your ApplicationController
#   helper :layout
module LayoutHelper
  def title(page_title, show_title = true)
    content_for(:title) { h(page_title.to_s) }
    @show_title = show_title
  end

  def show_title?
    @show_title
  end

  def stylesheet(*args)
    content_for(:head) { stylesheet_link_tag(*args) }
  end

  def javascript(*args)
    content_for(:head) { javascript_include_tag(*args) }
  end

end
```

Comment: Is your CSS inline in the `HEAD` or referenced by a `LINK` tag? If tag, please show us the code.

Comment: I don't think it's the CSS. Start a new project and slowly add things from the old one until it breaks. Try to break it. Create a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/).

Comment: Kevin- Since I'm developing in rails I have a separate stylesheet with the css and another file with the html & ruby and it's automatically linked- I think that's what you mean? Bookcasey - I'll try to work through that.

Comment: Added my layout helper, is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Have you run it through Firebug? Is the css file getting loaded on heroku? Have you tried another style (a simpler one) for the div?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, so I'd love to hear from you if you find a  solution.

Comment: nope. I just finished rewriting all of my code. Serious issue. Rendering incompatibility between local rails server and heroku?? or.. could i have old repo on git or something? I'm gonna post another question with updated findings I think.

Comment: Could the answer be similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056684/css-is-looking-different-on-heroku